# Is unsealed meat unacceptable?

Tags: food-safety

My question is really simple:

Is completely (vacuum) sealing leftover meat in the freezer absolutely necessary? I would always just use a plastic bag to cover the meat and fold it around couple of times so it's almost as good as sealed (usually grocery plastic bag is much bigger than the piece of meat) and have never had a problem with it last a decade or so I have been cooking.

But recently I got this new roommate who insists on me using special small plastic bags with sealers to use and he is being very paranoid, obsessive about it.

So my question is: Is he right?

Comment: I think this question belongs more to the SeasonedAdvice part of this website. I think, from the health perspective, there should not be any important difference between the bag with or without air around the meat. There will be more bacteria on the meat surface than in the air in the bag, anyway. The problem could be that the air left in the bag contains some  moisture, which would freeze on the surface of the meat and eventually change the taste or texture of the meat. Again, cooks should know better...

Comment: Yeah, definitely not a health question. You can freeze food in no wrappers at all and it will be perfectly safe. Dried out and ruined within days, but safe for years.Seasoned Advice is definitely where you want to ask this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about health.

Comment: How are you generating the vacuum?